# How to uninstall .vsix Visual Studio Extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xna, uninstallation, vsix

I am currently trying to install the XNA Game Studio for Visual Studio Express 2013. And I accidentally ran the .vsix program BEFORE actually installing the XNA framework.

After installing it and re-running the .vsix, I get a message error saying that the extension has already been installed. Which is not false.

I have tried a lot of things to "delete" the empty extension : going in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio and trying to find the extension, but finding myself with nothing, for example.

I would like to know how I can properly uninstall and reinstall the framework.

Comment: Tools -> Addin Manager?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

In the menu, go to:

- Visual Studio 2017: **Tools > Extensions And Updates**
- Visual Studio 2019: **Extensions > Manage Extensions**

A new window will pop up, then in the panel to the left, click the arrow besides **Installed** to bring it down and select the menu item **All**.

All you have to do now is to navigate in the middle panel to your installed exstension, select it and click **Uninstall**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I am new to VS, so I don't know everything about it, so thanks a lot :)

Comment: Uninstall programatically using powershell ?

Comment: This doesn't work if the extension gives an error on startup, then it never shows up for uninstall or removal.

Comment: I had this problem with the NVDA nsight extension as I trying to use an older version as recommended for ml.net.  The solution for me was to install current version that did not use deprecated api's.  At this point the error is gone and you can uninstall from within VS if you like.  This was easier for me than tracking down the extension id.

Answer (score 78):

To expand on the answer from @Brukvoyed, you can use the VSIXInstaller.exe utility to uninstall a vsix, but you need the vsixid to do so. To get the vsixid of a .vsix file, make a copy of the .vsix file and rename it to .zip. You can then open it and find an extension.vsixmanifest file inside. This is an XML file, and if you open it you will see an `<Identity Id="guid"... />` node. The `guid` is the vsixid you use in the VSIXInstaller.exe command, like this:

```
vsixinstaller /u:12345678-1234-5678-1234-123456780000
```

Comment: This helped me - except I found the ID I required in <Identifier Id="xxxx"> rather than Identity.

Comment: @JonH That's strange. I just checked another VSIX and it uses <Identity Id="e6e2a48e.... Oh well, glad you got what you needed.

Comment: BE CAREFUL WITH THIS:- make sure only to use a GUID or package ID that came from a vsixmanifest file. I used this command and (incorrectly) included a version number (`vsixinstaller /u:PowerShellTools.VS2017,version=3.0.585`), and it hosed my Visual Studio installation; now I can't access Packages & Extensions, and Visual Studio Repair doesn't work either. I'll likely need to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: You can find this id in your project. Open source.extension.vsixmanifest. The value you need is in the "Product ID:" field.

Comment: if the Id is more then just a GUID you will need to wrap it in quotes ```vsixinstaller.exe /admin /uninstall:"D365DeveloperExtensions.Jason Lattimer.ae772bae-97ff-47fa-8741-778a3c776740"```

Comment: In case you wonder where the executable is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE>

Answer (score 13):

In case Visual Studio does not start or cannot display the Extensions And Updates management window you may try to uninstall the extension from the command line. Use the VSIXInstaller.exe utility from standard VIsual Studio package.

Comment: Deleting C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_[somenumber]\privateregistry.bin might also help. Also see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31263/vs2017-fails-to-start-with-unknown-error.html

Comment: Example of using VSIXInstaller from cmd:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE>VSIXInstaller.exe /uninstall:PowerCommands.3ecdd89b-f985-483d-8c94-be37de4dc083

Extension ID can be found https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/ in right pannel, section Resources

Answer (score 11):

For VS2015, check your

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions
```

folder. I had to manually delete quite a few to remove the extensions that I didn't need. Inside each folder is a file named:

```
extension.vsixmanifest
```

and inside that file you can look at the DisplayName/Description to see what the extension is.

Comment: This is the correct answer when it fail to install or uninstall

Answer (score 5):

To look under the hood for .vsix extensions, here's one way:

1. Open Visual Studio command prompt
2. Run an invalid uninstall command

   `vsixinstaller /uninstall:abc123`
3. On the error dialog, click the link to the log.
4. The log contains a number of details, including all of the installed extensions and their locations.
5. In a particularly interesting extension location, list out descriptions with

```
    cd /d <interesting path>
    findstr /is Description extension.vsixmanifest
```

6. Once the desired extension is located via the description, open its extension.vsixmanifest to obtain the `<Identity>` GUID. Then uninstall:

   `vsixinstaller /uninstall:801375CB-9A15-A641-CB2D-50D43AAD43DC`

Answer (score 2):

**For Visual Studio 2019:**

In the Visual Studio menu, goto: **Extensions > Manage Extensions**.

Then from the side panel of the pop up window, select **Installed**. This will show all of your installed VS extensions.

[image]

Comment: How about when you uninstall the extension, vsix installer runs and says it uninstalled the extension and when you open VS2019 and check the extensions its still there?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with a LiveShare.UI (beta) which broke my Visual Studio UI so could not use the menus at all or do anything. I was going to use Visual Studio installer to repair Visual Studio, but that would probably remove all my extensions. So I picked the Update Visual Studio option instead, and now everything works again. Happy days.

Comment: The error message I got in VS was "ShareWorkspaceUIPackage did not load correctly", although I didn't realize it was caused by LiveShare. This solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and how I solved it was by not opening the solution. Just open visual studio, and navigate to Tools -> Extensions and Updates. The visual studio extension finally showed for now. When I opened the solution, and navigated to Tools -> Extensions and Updates it wouldn't show the visual studio extension.

Hopefully this saves someone some time...

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 problems on VS2017:

### Cannot find the extension

If you installed it through the **New Project... > *Online*** grouping/tab or downloaded and installed it directly:

1. in **Tools > Extensions And Updates** window click on the *Online* tab at the left sidemenu;
2. then click on the search bar at the top right (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>);
3. type part of the name of the extension and it now should show up at the center of the window;
4. Click the `Uninstall` button.

### The `Uninstall` or `Disable` button doesn't show up

After finding the extension, if there's a **green check mark** at the right top corner of the extension: it means you are **still using the extension in one of your solutions**.

So you need to remove the "inner" solution of your main solution that uses that extension:

1. backup any files you want to keep manually;
2. In the *Solution Explorer* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) click on the "inner" solution/folder (normally it has the same name as the solution itself).
3. hit <kbd>Del</kbd> and OK;
4. perform the steps mentioned above (through the **Tools > Extensions And Updates** window).

Comment: What I called as _"inner" solution_ is a _Project_ inside the _Solution_.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here are instructions for how to uninstall multiple extension with a DOS batch script.

- **Reason for my uninstall necessity:**
  On my VS2022 installation, I installed over 20 Extensions on a day before my computer systems files were corrupted, and I had to restore Windows 11 to a restore point.
  That caused a deletion of all the DLL for the extensions I installed.

To uninstall multiple extensions, I looked at the following folder:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio**[!17.0_60f34b7d!]**\Extensions

Make sure to change the above path to your **user name** and to the VisualStudio **sub-folder**.

I sorted the folders listed in that path by "Date Modified", which let me identify all the extensions installed on the specific date.
I then went into each folder, and open **extension.vsixmanifest**.
That file contains the vsixID needed for the uninstall command.

```
<PackageManifest Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2011">
  <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="65dd734b-180a-4c67-b245-56de889637e1" Version="2022.2" Language="en-US" Publisher="Mike Ward - Ann Arbor" />
```

I copied the **Identity Id** from each **extension.vsixmanifest** file, and pasted all of them into a text file.

```
7671c1a9-8269-44eb-9b9a-bd8bec0af629
PREVIEW-INI.EC198F83-B43E-48F7-A346-3BA545D132DE
RenameVariableAfterType.09d7f563-5d3d-405b-8232-ee07e19139b9
b4558cd7-da41-47e7-8969-46c357a1b8b3
DocumentationAssistant.64c7f98c-bf02-4a60-9f8e-9ca5fd269fd7
```

Then using Notepad++ (you can also use VS), I held the ALT key and scrolled from the top to the bottom at the start of the lines.
Then I just pasted "vsixinstaller /q /uninstall:".

```
vsixinstaller /q /uninstall:7671c1a9-8269-44eb-9b9a-bd8bec0af629
vsixinstaller /q /uninstall:PREVIEW-INI.EC198F83-B43E-48F7-A346-3BA545D132DE
vsixinstaller /q /uninstall:RenameVariableAfterType.09d7f563-5d3d-405b-8232-ee07e19139b9
vsixinstaller /q /uninstall:b4558cd7-da41-47e7-8969-46c357a1b8b3
vsixinstaller /q /uninstall:DocumentationAssistant.64c7f98c-bf02-4a60-9f8e-9ca5fd269fd7
```

After that I save the text file to a batch file (vsixUninstall.bat), and executed the script from the folder containing **vsixinstaller.exe**.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE>C:\Temp\vsixUninstall.bat
```

With my script I use the /q option to avoid getting a prompt after each uninstall.  It ran all the uninstalls without any user input. But if there's an extension that is not getting uninstall, it's a good idea to remove the /q option so as to get more details on the failure.

Hope this helps. [image]