# Upgrading VS 2017 Extensions to VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, vsix, vsct

I installed VS 2019 and wanted to install an extension that I had developed myself and which ran under VS 2017. I just double-clicked the VSIX file, and the VS installer told me that the extension had been installed and OK. However, I cannot see it in my tools menu where it used to be; the keystroke does not function either.
I can remember I had similar phenomena when I had updated to 2017 from an earlier version; I re-complied the source code under VS 2019, but when I try to install it, the manager tells that the extension has been OK installed already.
Presumably I need to delete the attached VSCT file (?), but how can I find it? Or, better, how can I uninstall an extension I do not see in the extension manager?

Comment: In the meantime, I found an answer to the question of how to "programmatically" uninstall an invisible extension (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444799/how-to-uninstall-vsix-visual-studio-extensions).
After a few attempts, it did function. But the rest is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I really needed to manually uninstall the VSIX using the method mentioned in my comment (vsixinstaller.exe which is in something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE" - add this to your PATH for simplicity).
In my case, however, it did not want to function with the option /u:, but only as

```
vsixinstaller.exe /uninstall:<ID>
```

however, this worked fine.

In the manifest file of the VSIX project (source.extension.vsixmanifest) the following value for the tag InstallationTarget appeared to be correct for VS 2019:

```
<InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[15.0, 17.0)" />
```