# No tests discovered in Visual Studio with error "The SVsFileChangeEx service is unavailable"

Tags: visual-studio, xunit, test-explorer

What to do, if I don't see my xUnit tests discovered in the Test Explorer panel, and the Tests tab in the Output toolbox contains the error: "The SVsFileChangeEx service is unavailable".

Answer (score 0):

First, [uninstall the xUnit runner extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22445013/3734141), if you have one. Second, [install the runner as the NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio).